# Using JGit to try to access stash repository. Dont know what credentials to provide

Tags: git, credentials, jgit, bitbucket-server

I am using JGit to call

```
cloneRepository().setURI().setDirectory().setCredentialsProvider().call();
```

I am currently using UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider() to try to provide the information that stash needs but I am getting an error that says UnsupportedCredentialItem.  I am wondering if anyone knows specifically what stash needs in order to perform a git clone through JGit.

Thanks for you help

Comment: From what I understand it uses either HTTP auth (using your Jira/Crowd credentials) or SSH (using a stored key).

Comment: I think its the SSH key,  do you know how to add an SSH credentialItem?  Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http protocol and pass in a username /password.

In case you want to use the ssh protocol, make sure you have the ssh keys stored in Stash for the userid. In that case , stash does the authentication behind the scenes and you do not need  to provide username/password